# itextsharp firefox black background

Tags: firefox, pdf, pdf.js

first time in stackoverflow :)

Let me explain what happend. I'm trying to create a PDF using iTextSharp. It displays perfectly in chrome and IE9, but in firefox the background is black.

firefox version
[image]

chrome version
[image]

Best!

Comment: Can you please **show us your code**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd inspect the PDF with Adobe Acrobat for syntax errors, the report would probably be blank. There's a 99% chance that the problem is caused by pdf.js, NOT by iText(Sharp). For some reason (ask Mozilla, don't ask me), using pdf.js is now the standard way to view PDFs in Firefox. Unfortunately, pdf.js is far from being a full-fledged PDF viewer. It doesn't support forms, it doesn't support signatures, it doesn't support many graphical objects,... It lacks many of the PDF functionality as described in ISO-32000-1.

I changed the settings in Firefox, so that it now opens PDFs in Adobe Reader, but I didn't manage to use Adobe Reader as a plug-in in Firefox the way it used to be in the past. All of this is very frustrating.